# RStudio won't open some text files

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

Lately I'm having a strange problem with RStudio (v**1.3.1056** on Ubuntu 18.04): When I try to open some text files, RStudio refuses with the message `file is binary rather than text`:

[image: file is binary rather than text]

Yet, the file I'm trying to open is definitely a text file. As an example, take this bibtex file:

```
@misc{test,
 author = {test},
 year = {2018},
 title = {test},
}
```

When I try to open it with the file name "test.bib", I get the error above. When renaming it to "test.txt" RStudio opens it without complaining. Here the steps as `R` code:

```
rstudioapi::navigateToFile("test.bib") # won't work
file.copy("test.bib", "test.txt", overwrite = TRUE)
rstudioapi::navigateToFile("test.txt") # works perfectly
```

I'm pretty sure that RStudio wouldn't mind the file ending and just try to open files as text no matter what in the past. But now I either have to rename the file or get a different text editor to edit my bib and other files.

As far as I can tell, this is not a problem of Ubuntu marking the file as binary. Otherwise one of these commands would complain, I think:

```
readLines("test.bib")
system("grep 'misc' test.bib")
```

Comment: With RStudio 1.3.959 on MacOS Catalina I am able to open test.bib and edit it. I also downloaded and tested this on RStudio 1.3.1056, which is the most recent version. Update your RStudio to this version and see whether you can edit the file. If you still can't edit the file, you can edit the file with the [Atom](https://atom.io) text editor.

Comment: Thanks for testing! 1.3.1056is the version I'm already using (as mentioned at the top). I tested an earlier version as well to rule out that this was recently introduced. If it works on macos, It's probably an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Sorry, missed the RStudio version in your question. You might want to post a question on the [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us) site and see whether they can explain the difference in behavior between Mac OS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to confirm your hypothesis that previous versions of RStudio don't mind: With 1.1.463 it works absolutely fine under Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem is rather stupid. Apparently it is possible in Linux to include newline characters in your folder name, yet either RStudio or `file` doesn't like that. I had no idea that my `test.bib` file was sitting in a folder with a newline character. So the problem can be reproduced with:

```
bib <- "@misc{test,
 author = {test},
 year = {2018},
 title = {test},
}"
dir.create("test\nfolder")
writeLines(bib, "./test\nfolder/test.bib")

rstudioapi::navigateToFile("./test\nfolder/test.bib") # throws error
```

While it works when the folder is just called "test folder"! Sorry for wasting people's time, I should have just tested it elsewhere...

Comment: I'm getting this same error but there are no newline characters in the file path of my .bib file. The error occurs when I click on the .bib file in the RStudio file viewer pane. However, I am able to open the file inside RStudio using `rstudioapi::navigateToFile(...)`

Comment: I think this will happen if you have any illegal characters in your file path. Try placing the file in your home directory and name it `test.bib` and see what happens. If you still get your error, it must be something else.

Comment: Hmm I tried what you suggested and am still getting the same error. Also, the rstudioapi::navigateToFile(...) method stopped working! I *can* open the file in BBEdit though.

Comment: I think you are having a different problem then. Maybe post a new question?

Comment: Posted on the [RStudio community forum](https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-open-bib-file-in-rstudio/107892)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the current test of whether a file is text or not here:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/d1289249b11e0d12d2be12b3ceb701c41f110cec/src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp#L1216.  It looks for a recorded MIME type according to the filename extension (and `.bib` isn't in the list currently, so that will fail).

It then tries to run

```
file --dereference --mime --brief test.bib
```

and looks at the result.  Maybe your system doesn't recognize `test.bib` as `text/plain`?  A few other types would also be recognized as text; see the end of that function on github.

Comment: The `file` command fails with `file: could not find any valid magic files!` for all files. I guess that's probably the problem. Maybe my installation of "file" got somehow corrupted. Thanks for explaining this. It helps a lot.

Comment: If I run just `file test.bib`, the result is `test.bib: ASCII text`. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer:  it should have had `--mime`, not `-mime`.  (I'll fix it in a minute.) That's an important option, because it produces output in the format RStudio is looking for.  With no options, it looks as though `file` is recognizing the file as being ascii text, so this may be progress.

Comment: Ah thanks!. Now it's working. The output: `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`. So everything should be fine. But RStudio still refuses to open it :(

Comment: That's definitely an RStudio bug worth reporting to them.

Comment: Unbelievable. I just noticed I had a newline character in the folder name of the directory I was testing all this. When the newline is remove, it works. Thank you so much for your help!